# diagram design with Visio and Open Source

Tags: visio, file-format, dia, libreoffice-draw

I have different people working on a diagram. One of them draws his diagrams in Visio, the other people use Open Source solutions, such as Dia and Libre Office Draw.

Does anyone know in which format they best can import/ export the diagram, so that everyone can view and edit the diagram? 
In other words, which format can best be used if one diagram has to be edited in three different editors (Visio, Dia and LO-Draw)?

And yes, I know the best solution is to persuade them to all use Dia or Libre Office, but those MS-minded people are hard to persuade... ;-)

Comment: Interesting question (allthough I'm not sure it fits here ?), I've always felt there was a missing standard in that field. Maybe you can expand: what kind of diagrams is it about ? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram)

Comment: It's a simple flow-diagram. All three editors can import and export several file formats, but often each editor interprets a file-format slightly different, so there can be deviations in what everybody sees.

I'm going to find someone in the office who has Visio installed and experiment a bit. I will get back to you if I find out which format gives the best results..

Comment: I am looking at LibreOffice Draw, version 7.3.4.2, and don't see any Visio-compatible export options in the "Save As" menu.  Only things there are image / vector graphics file types.